# Nginx allow via Domain but not via the IP

Tags: nginx

This is my configuration:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name  domain.tld www.domain.tld;
    return 301 https://erp.uni.mk$request_uri;
}
server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    server_name  domain.tld;
    ssl_certificate "/etc/nginx/ssl/ca_full.crt";
    ssl_certificate_key "/etc/nginx/ssl/private.key";
    ...
}
```

What I am trying to achieve is block access via the IP. And only allow it via the domain.

I've seen some solutions with regex, but I am using both IPv4 and IPv6. And it should not impact performance.

Any suggestions how to solve this?

Comment: You could add a `server` block that only listens to the IP, then redirect those request, this way you don;t have to edit the existing blocks. `server { listen 80; server_name 1.1.1.1; return 301 http://something; }`

Comment: @0stone0 I know, but I was looking for an approach where I don't have to bother with changing IP addresses. Cause I'll be using the same config for multiple servers.

Comment: If you first create a block that'll lissen to the domain names, then a (default) block that listen to 'the rest' (empty server_name, or the 'default' option) you don't need to list the IP

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to define a catch all server. Use the `default_server` parameter on the `listen` directive.

For example:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen 443 ssl default_server;

    ssl_certificate /path/to/any/cert.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /path/to/any/key.pem;

    return 444;
}
```

The server needs a certificate to block `https` connections, any certificate will do. The client's browser will throw warnings, but they shouldn't be trying to connect to a secure server without a correct domain name anyway.

The `server_name` directive is not required. The non-standard code 444 closes the connection without sending a response header.

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html#miscellaneous_names) for details.

Comment: Use `nginx -T` (uppercase `T`) to test the configuration and ensure you see the new `server` block. Clear the browser cache after restarting the Nginx server.

Comment: I get this via HTTP/2: `curl: (92) HTTP/2 stream 1 was not closed cleanly: INTERNAL_ERROR (err 2)`

Comment: Is there any other way to close the connection without returning anything?

Comment: The 444 status is rude, it just hangs up the connection. AFAIK the only alternative is so send a valid response, e.g. 403, 404 or 301.